# Is there any way to create Databricks jobCluster through Databricks connect?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-workflows

Is there any way to create Databricks jobCluster through Databricks connect?
We are using All purposed cluster so far, to reduce Databricks cost we are planning to go ahead with jobCluster but unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to create jobCluster through Databricks connect.
Or is there any alternate way to by-pass the Databricks connect and create job cluster through IDE (PyCharm)

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Connect is designed to work only with interactive clusters, as it itself is also used for interactive work. So you can't use it with job clusters.

Alternatively, you can look onto the [dbx tool](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html) from Databricks labs that allows you to use local IDE to develop a code, but then run the tests on the job or interactive clusters.  But take into account that it won't allow you to debug interactively the code running on the Databricks - you can do it only against the local Spark.